# range of $f(x,y) = (e^x\cos y,e^x \sin y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

range of $f(x,y) = (e^x\cos y,e^x \sin y)$. I think it is all of $\mathbb{R^2}$ as $f$ can take any value of $x,y$ and $|\cos y| \leq 1$ as well as and the range of the function $y = e^x$ is $y\geq 0$. I am unsure if this is correct or how I would prove it

Comment: Look at the 2-norm of $f(x,y)$. Can it be zero?

Comment: no it cannot, see my comment below.

Comment: Why don’t you simply take a point $(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2\setminus(0,0)$, and find an $(x,y)$ that maps to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Are you sure that $e^x \ge 0$?

As far as proving it, your method of reasoning is sound. Each of $\{e^u, \cos u, \sin u\}$ can accept any $u \in \mathbb{R}$. Next declare what mapping $e^x \cos y$ produces. I suppose we could write that it takes $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. This is the same for $e^x \sin y$. So, yes, the function $f$ can be described as $$f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$$

---

edit: forgot the 2 on $\mathbb{R^2}$ in the last line.

edit2: probably should have written that we exclude $(0,0)$ and not $0$ in the last line, as this is 2-space.

Comment: sorry I mean $e^x > 0$. So the range is all of $z$ but $z = 0$?

Comment: Yeah. Consider $(a \cos \theta, a \sin \theta)$. This is a parametrized circle of radius $a$. So the sinuisoidals rotate us about the origin, and the exponential (replaced by the constant $a$ here) defines a radius. Since $e^x \ne 0$, we do not get the origin.